# oAuth and that bio-digital jazz

Tags: php, oauth, tumblr

So, i'm a fairly beginner in oAuth and i'm wanting to write a simple wrapper for Tumblr since i'm craving to make an iPad HTML5 App.

The thing is, i can't seem to find any clear documentation on how to exactly set up everything for oAuth-php. I can make a two legged request, and it works... but i want to be able to save users (three-legged) and retrive their dashboards (and i need need to make a GET request with authorized credentials).

I'm clueless on where to start.

Here's a somewhat vague documentation on the Tumblr API: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#user-methods

Comment: Well I am reading their API blog and they said: "Developers should be able to easily discover and experiment with an API without having to dig through piles of documentation." LOL http://engineering.tumblr.com/post/7541361718/introducing-tumblrs-new-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This document helped me quite a bit to get the whole authorization header stuff worked out: http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/